# How to focus on a specific day on a calender with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, calendar, html-table

I recently made my own calendar using html and CSS, now I want the calendar to have the possibility to choose a day and month from the dropdown list, so when I choose a date it will focus on the day and change its color

I have done some coding with Javascript but problem is it takes to much lines in Javascript, anyone knows an easier way?

JS Code:

```
        function selectDay() {
            var day = document.getElementById("day");
            var month = document.getElementById("month");
             var type = document.getElementById("type");
            var selectedValueday = day.options[day.selectedIndex].value;
            var selectedValuemonth = month.options[month.selectedIndex].value;
            var selectedValuetype = type.options[type.selectedIndex].value;


            if ((selectedValueday === "01") && (selectedValuemonth === "01") && (selectedValuetype === "01")) {
                document.getElementById('jan1').style.backgroundColor = 'purple';
            } else if((selectedValueday === "01") && (selectedValuemonth === "01") && (selectedValuetype === "02")){
                document.getElementById('jan1').style.backgroundColor = 'yellow';
            }else{
                document.getElementById('jan1').style.backgroundColor = 'white';
            }
          if ((selectedValueday === "02") && (selectedValuemonth === "01") && (selectedValuetype === "01")) {
                document.getElementById('jan2').style.backgroundColor = 'purple';
            } else if((selectedValueday === "02") && (selectedValuemonth === "01") && (selectedValuetype === "02")){
                document.getElementById('jan2').style.backgroundColor = 'yellow';
            }else{
                document.getElementById('jan2').style.backgroundColor = 'white';
            }
        }
```

HTML Code:

```
<select id="day">
        <option>Kies een dag</option>
        <option value="01">01</option>
        <option value="02">02</option>
        <option value="03">03</option>
        <option value="04">04</option>
        <option value="05">05</option>
        <option value="06">06</option>
        <option value="07">07</option>
        <option value="08">08</option>
        <option value="09">09</option>
        <option value="10">10</option>
        <option value="11">11</option>
        <option value="12">12</option>
        <option value="13">13</option>
        <option value="14">14</option>
        <option value="15">15</option>
        <option value="16">16</option>
        <option value="17">17</option>
        <option value="18">18</option>
        <option value="19">19</option>
        <option value="20">20</option>
        <option value="21">21</option>
        <option value="22">22</option>
        <option value="23">23</option>
        <option value="24">24</option>
        <option value="25">25</option>
        <option value="26">26</option>
        <option value="27">27</option>
        <option value="28">28</option>
        <option value="29">29</option>
        <option value="30">30</option>
        <option value="31">31</option>
    </select>
    <select id="month">
        <option>Kies een maand</option>
        <option value="01">01</option>
        <option value="02">02</option>
        <option value="03">03</option>
        <option value="04">04</option>
        <option value="05">05</option>
        <option value="06">06</option>
        <option value="07">07</option>
        <option value="08">08</option>
        <option value="09">09</option>
        <option value="10">10</option>
        <option value="11">11</option>
        <option value="12">12</option>
    </select>
    <select id="type">
        <option>Kies een type</option>
        <option value="01">Feestdag</option>
        <option value="02">Verjaardag</option>
    </select>

    <button onclick="selectDay();">Zoek</button>

        <h1 align='center'>Jaarkalender 2013</h1>
        <table align='center' width = '1600'  border = '0'>
            <tr>
                <td ALIGN="center"><B>Januari</B>
                    <table  height = '175' border = '0'>
                        <tr>
                            <TD bgcolor='B9B1B1'><b><b>Maandag</b></b><FONT COLOR="B9B1B1">.</FONT></TD>
                            <TD bgcolor='B9B1B1'><b>Dinsdag</b> <FONT COLOR="B9B1B1">.</FONT></TD>        
                            <TD bgcolor='B9B1B1'><b>Woensdag</b> <FONT COLOR="B9B1B1">.</FONT></TD>
                            <TD bgcolor='B9B1B1'><b>Donderdag</b> <FONT COLOR="B9B1B1">.</FONT></TD>
                            <TD bgcolor='B9B1B1'><b>Vrijdag</b> <FONT COLOR="B9B1B1">.</FONT></TD>
                            <TD bgcolor='B9B1B1'><b>Zaterdag</b> <FONT COLOR="B9B1B1">.</FONT></TD>
                            <TD bgcolor='B9B1B1'><b>Zondag</b> <FONT COLOR="B9B1B1">.</FONT></TD>
                        </tr>
                        <TR>
                            <TD><font color="#888888">30</font></TD>
                            <TD id="jan1" title = 'Nieuwjaar'><font color = '#FF0000'><B>1</B></TD>
                            <TD id="jan2">2</TD>
                            <TD>3</TD>
                            <TD>4</TD>
                            <TD bgcolor='#00FFFF'>5</TD>
                            <TD bgcolor='#00FFFF'>6</TD>
                        </TR>
                        <TR>
                            <TD>7</TD>
                            <TD>8</TD>
                            <TD>9</TD>
                            <TD>10</TD>
                            <TD>11</TD>
                            <TD bgcolor='#00FFFF'>12</TD>
                            <TD bgcolor='#00FFFF'>13</TD>
                        </TR>
                        <TR>
                            <TD>14</TD>
                            <TD>15</TD>
                            <TD>16</TD>
                            <TD>17</TD>
                            <TD>18</TD>
                            <TD bgcolor='#00FFFF'>19</TD>
                            <TD bgcolor='#00FFFF'>20</TD>
                        </TR>
                        <TR>
                            <TD>21</TD>
                            <TD>22</TD>
                            <TD>23</TD>
                            <TD>24</TD>
                            <TD>25</TD>
                            <TD bgcolor='#00FFFF'>26</TD>
                            <TD bgcolor='#00FFFF'>27</TD>
                        </TR>
                        <TR>
                            <TD>28</TD>
                            <TD>29</TD>
                            <TD>30</TD>
                            <TD>31</TD>
                            <TD><font color="#888888">1</font></TD>
                            <TD bgcolor='#00FFFF'><font color="#888888">2</font></TD>
                            <TD bgcolor='#00FFFF'><font color="#888888">3</font></TD>
                        </TR>
                        <TR>
                            <TD></TD>
                            <TD></TD>
                            <TD></TD>
                            <TD></TD>
                            <TD></TD>
                            <TD  bgcolor='#00FFFF'></TD>
                            <TD  bgcolor='#00FFFF'></TD>
                        </TR>
                    </table>
                </TD>

                <td ALIGN="center"><B>Februari</B>
                    <table border = '0' height = '175'>
                        <tr>
                            <TD bgcolor='B9B1B1'><b><b>Maandag</b></b> <FONT COLOR="B9B1B1">.</FONT></TD>
                            <TD bgcolor='B9B1B1'><b>Dinsdag</b> <FONT COLOR="B9B1B1">.</FONT></TD>        
                            <TD bgcolor='B9B1B1'><b>Woensdag</b> <FONT COLOR="B9B1B1">.</FONT></TD>
                            <TD bgcolor='B9B1B1'><b>Donderdag</b> <FONT COLOR="B9B1B1">.</FONT></TD>
                            <TD bgcolor='B9B1B1'><b>Vrijdag</b> <FONT COLOR="B9B1B1">.</FONT></TD>
                            <TD bgcolor='B9B1B1'><b>Zaterdag</b> <FONT COLOR="B9B1B1">.</FONT></TD>
                            <TD bgcolor='B9B1B1'><b>Zondag</b> <FONT COLOR="B9B1B1">.</FONT></TD>
                        </tr>
                        <TR>
                            <TD><font color="#888888">28</font></TD>
                            <TD><font color="#888888">29</font></TD>
                            <TD><font color="#888888">30</font></TD>
                            <TD><font color="#888888">31</font></TD>
                            <TD>1</TD>
                            <TD bgcolor='#00FFFF'>2</TD>
                            <TD bgcolor='#00FFFF'>3</TD>
                        </TR>
                        <TR>
                            <TD>4</TD>
                            <TD>5</TD>
                            <TD>6</TD>
                            <TD>7</TD>
                            <TD>8</TD>
                            <TD bgcolor='#00FFFF'>9</TD>
                            <TD bgcolor='#00FFFF'>10</TD>
                        </TR>
                        <TR>
                            <TD>11</TD>
                            <TD>12</TD>
                            <TD>13</TD>
                            <TD>14</TD>
                            <TD>15</TD>
                            <TD bgcolor='#00FFFF'>16</TD>
                            <TD bgcolor='#00FFFF'>17</TD>
                        </TR>
                        <TR>
                            <TD>18</TD>
                            <TD>19</TD>
                            <TD>20</TD>
                            <TD>21</TD>
                            <TD>22</TD>
                            <TD bgcolor='#00FFFF'>23</TD>
                            <TD bgcolor='#00FFFF'>24</TD>
                        </TR>
                        <TR>
                            <TD>25</TD>
                            <TD>26</TD>
                            <TD>27</TD>
                            <TD>28</TD>
                            <TD><font color="#888888">1</font></TD>
                            <TD bgcolor='#00FFFF'><font color="#888888">2</font></TD>
                            <TD bgcolor='#00FFFF'><font color="#888888">3</font></TD>
                        </TR>
                    </table>
                </TD>  
        </table>
```

CSS Code:

```
        table{

            left: -200px;
            border-collapse:collapse;
            border:1px solid black;
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give each of the table cells (the ones representing dates only) an individual id - they cant start with a number so I suggest use m then the month number d then the day number - eg id='m2d5' for the 5th February.

Then you can use the value of each of your SELECT elements to create the id and use:

```
 var dayid = "m"+month.value+"d"+day.value;
 document.getElementById('dayid').className = 'lit'
```

If you want only one cell highlighted you'll either have to keep track of the id of the cell you last lit or use something like

```
var reset = document.getElementsByClassName("lit");
while (reset.length) { reset[0].className = "normal"; }
```

To find and reset any lit ones..

Comment: hi thanks for your comment, 
hoewer it still didnt work, i dont know what you mean by the classnames and dayid , could you please be a little more specific.
i may sound stupid but im just a beginner at javascript and dont really understand all you said.
thanks again

Comment: The className references a CSS style - you've only got one set up for Table at the moment but for testing add something like .lit { background-color:#ff0000; } (including the dot before lit) to your CSS code. Then anything the Javascript sets to class 'lit' will have its background set to red.

Comment: thankyou very much

i still have one more problem. when ik select a date, i get an error on the consolelog "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'className' of null ". ans this is my JS code:

 function selectDay() {

var dayid = "d" + day.value + "m" + month.value;
document.getElementById(dayid).className='lit';
}

Comment: document.getElementById(dayid).className='lit'; AND document.getElementById('dayid').className='lit'; both does not work

Comment: But have you given all the relevant TD elements the appropriate id? You don't want the quotes around dayid - it's a variable.

Comment: well it's not finding something with the id you're generating in dayid so have a look at the value of that to see if it makes sense; check there's an element with that id. Make sure you've added some code to trap when the value of your select elements is null (eg when first displayed and nothing has been selected)